# How can I escape manually using the Database library with Kohana 3?

Tags: database, kohana, kohana-3

I need to quote a string a string in PHP using Kohana 3's Database library. In 2.3, all I had to do is `$this->db->escape()`.

How can I do this in 3? I seem to remember seeing something like `quote()` when I was viewing the source, but for the life of me can I find it again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `Database` class has a `escape()` method,  [look here](http://v3.kohanaphp.com/guide/api/Database#escape).

Comment: So I guess usage would be `DB::escape()` ?

Comment: You can execute `Database::instance()->escape($string)`.